# Is it always true that the charge on capacitors connected in series in a circuit same?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

In a parallel plate capacitor if we introduce a dielectric that fills halfway from one plate to another, then we can interpret the whole setup as two capacitors connected in series. But it's also mentioned (separately) that the charge appearing on the face of the slab of any dielectric is some function of the dielectric constant.

So is this some kind of exception or what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "a dielectric that fills halfway from one plate to another". You need to clarify what you mean by "halfway". This could be interpreted to be half way of the length of the plates, in which case you have parallel capacitors, or half way filling the space between the plates in which case you have capacitors in series.

Answer (score 0):

If they are initially discharged, put in series, then charged this is true because of Kirchoff's current law. However, If you charged the capacitors separately then connected them in series this may not be true.

Also, from your problem wouldn't introducing a dielectric part of the way between plates be modeled as two parallel capacitors (one with and one without dielectric)? It seems this would be the case because the two capacitors are at the same voltage.